# How to import functions correctly (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, function, import, export

I'm trying to make an incremental game just for fun and to learn Javascript, I came from Java to Javascript and I can't figure it out how to import "classes" or "modules" from another package or folder

I tried to create a folder named `Minerals` and inside of it I have `gold.js`, `iron.js` and `copper.js`

In `src` folder I have both `index.html` and `main.js` (main class)

Inside `gold.js` I have this piece of code:

```js
export {goldData, mineGold}

var goldData = {
    gold: 0,
    goldPerClick: 0,
    goldPerClickCost: null
}

function mineGold() {
    datosGold.gold += 1
    document.getElementById("amountOfGold").innerHTML ="Gold: " + goldData.gold
}
```

and in the `main.js` i tried many things, like creating mineGold() there and many other things without any success. And when I import `gold.js` all my functions inside `main.js` turn to "unused functions" and don't work when I call them from `index.html`

I imported the file like this (tried both):

```js
import {goldData, mineGold} from "./Minerals/oro" //option 1
import * as todo from "./Minerals/oro" //option 2
```

When I try to use the button linked to `mineGold()` from `index.html` I get:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: mineGold is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick
```

Here's the full code but in Spanish (since I'm from ARG): https://github.com/FacuFu/VicionariiMiner

Basic question is:
How to use functions defined in a `.js` file from an `.html` file if the `.js` file use `import` from another `.js` file

**Also you can directly see the webpage trough:** http://facufu.tk

Comment: GitHub files may be different from here, that's why I been trying many things but I can't get it already

Answer (score 0):

Use this to be run
`todo.function()`