# In VS Code is it possible to open an imported function from it's calling function?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

In VSCode, I'm using an imported function within another function - in two separate files. If I "peek" at the imported function definition, it shows me the line where the function has been imported - but I don't seem to be able to navigate to that imported function directly. I still have to do a find for that function and open the file from the search box.

Ideally, I'd like to just click on the function name from within the file that I'm currently working on and open the imported function in a new tab. I feel like I'm missing something. Is that possible? Thanks.

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67639402/how-to-import-functions-correctly-javascript/67639618#67639618

Comment: @TusharShahi - thanks for the response, but no I don't think so. I'm importing / exporting the js correctly. This isn't really a syntax issue - js is working fine. I'd say this is more to do with navigating VS Code efficiently - saying that, there are multiple exports in the one file. I wonder if that makes a difference.

Comment: Apologies I pasted the wrong link. Try this one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52081768/how-i-can-make-ctrl-click-to-go-to-definition-in-visual-studio-code-editor-f

Comment: Aah that makes sense, thanks. Yes - so I still have the same problem - still not navigating to the definition, but I am now also seeing "Implementation not found" appear as a tooltip on the import function. Doing a quick web search points to a number of cases where this happens so will look into this now.

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in function that VS Code has that will do this. Highlight the function and do the following shortcuts.

- 'CTRL' : Will give you an in line preview of the function definition.
- 'F12' : Will take you to the function  definition in whatever file its in.
- 'Shift F12' : Will give you a bigger peak of the file definition. It will open another window but keep you at the file you are at.

Here is the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved) on VS Code that explains it. Search for 'definition' and you will see some sections on it.

Note: That yes this does work but not in all cases. For example, with built-in functions with a language this will not work. If you define the function in a file somewhere it will find that. If you need this to work with a built-in function or CSS. Something like that you will have to install an extension for that language or do what you're doing and search for it.

Comment: Thanks @peter-dev - yeah, that's what I was expecting to happen but it doesn't seem to work. I see "Implementation not found" as a tooltip when I CMD + F12 (I'm on a Mac) over the imported function. And I see "import {functionName} from 'path/tofunction' as the peek, rather than seeing the imported function.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Javascript @peter-dev